# Dunst notifier on CentOS

Tags: linux, notifications

I need a notifier such that:

1. It is possible to send messages from one machine to another without any password (like in case of notify-send). Correct me if I'm wrong.
2. It is such that only when a user clicks on cross button that it closes.

I found Dunst while searching. it needs basic packages.

```
dbus
libxinerama
libxft
libxss
libxdg-basedir
```

out of which, I'm not able to get `libxdg-basedir` installed on my system. I tried searching for it, but there aren't any packages available for CentOS.

Question: is it possible to compile and install Dunst (or a notifier) on CentOS? If so how?

Comment: Which CentOS do you have? 5 or 6?

Comment: Description: CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

Answer (score 0):

I started to build Dunst on CentOS 6 but ran into a myriad of dependencies on `libxdg-basedir` which made it a fairly arduous task, so I abandoned trying to compile it.

Looking for alternatives I did come across `notification-daemon` which seems to be what you want.

*excerpt*

> notification-daemon is the server implementation of the freedesktop.org desktop notification specification. Notifications can be used to inform the user
>   about an event or display some form of information without getting in the user's way.

This seems to be what you want.

[image: ss #1]

#### References

- [Desktop Notifications - ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_Notifications)